# rEFind doal boot option disappeared after ubuntu 14 to 16 upgrade

Tags: 14.04, refind

I had a dual boat rEFind with osx and ubuntu 14. I just upgraded to ubuntu 16. Now it doesn't appear at all. I get ubuntu on every startup without the usual boot screen I had.

Comment: rEFInd still in the boot partition?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've encountered what I call a [boot coup](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/bootcoup.html) -- the update from Ubuntu 14[.04?] to 16[.04?] has made GRUB the default boot manager, bypassing rEFInd. rEFInd is probably still installed and can be made the default again in several ways, or there are other things you might do:

- **Use `refind-mkdefault`** -- This script, which comes with rEFInd, will probably fix the problem. If you installed rEFInd in OS X, it won't be in the path from Ubuntu, so you'd need to find it on your OS X partition or obtain a version in Ubuntu. The most direct way is to [download it from rEFInd's Sourceforge repository.](https://sourceforge.net/p/refind/code/ci/master/tree/refind-mkdefault?format=raw)
- **Use `efibootmgr`** -- You can type `sudo efibootmgr -v` to see all your boot options and the current boot order (the `BootOrder` line). If you can figure out which option is rEFInd (it probably refers to `refind_x64.efi`), you can then change the boot order with the `-o` option, as in `sudo efibootmgr -o xxxx[,yyyy,zzzz]`, where `xxxx` is the `Boot####` option for rEFInd and subsequent numbers refer to alternative boot options. This is what `refind-mkdefault` does; the script just does it automatically.
- **Use `bless`** -- If you can boot to OS X (by using Alt or Option as you power on the computer), you can use the `bless` utility in OS X to restore rEFInd as the main boot program. You'd follow steps 1, 2, and 8 in the [manual rEFInd OS X installation procedure.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/installing.html#osx) Note that, if you're using a recent version of OS X, you might run into problems with [SIP.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/sip.html)
- **Re-install rEFInd** -- You could install the rEFInd PPA or Debian package in Ubuntu; or use the Alt or Option key as you power on the computer to do a one-time boot to OS X and re-install rEFInd there. This option is overkill, and so might accidentally make a change you don't intend, but it can be relatively easy. On Macs, I recommend doing the re-installation from OS X if possible, although you might run into issues with SIP.
- **Keep using GRUB** -- Presumably GRUB is controlling the boot process now. In theory, it *should* show you a boot menu that will enable booting either Ubuntu or OS X; however, it's not clear from your description if that's the case. If not, or if the OS X option doesn't work, [GRUB Customizer](https://launchpad.net/~danielrichter2007/+archive/ubuntu/grub-customizer) might help you get it working better.

Your personal preferences and skill level come into play, but overall, I'd say you should try these options in more-or-less the order noted.